# How to call a class object buildin a c# dll in rust?

Tags: c#, rust, dll

Since i have to use other dll functions like

```cs
[DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern void SHAddToRecentDocs(ShellAddToRecentDocsFlags flags, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string file);
```

I build my c# dll with such struct

```cs
namespace MyObject
{
   public class MyObjectHandler
   {
      ...some dll import
      public MyObjectHandler() {}

      public void my_function1(){...}
      ...
   }
}
```

Then when i try to use them in rust, i found that `libloading` or `sharelib` only supports calling dll functions, rather than calling some classes.

If try directly call class or functions in class like the code below

```rust
fn call_dynamic() -> Result<bool, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    unsafe {
        let program_exe_path = current_exe().unwrap();
        let dll_path = program_exe_path.parent().unwrap().join("ClassLibrary1.dll");
        println!("path {}", dll_path.display());
        if dll_path.exists() {
            let lib = libloading::Library::new(dll_path.to_str().unwrap())?;
            println!("Load dll success!");
            let func: libloading::Symbol<unsafe extern fn() -> bool> = lib.get(b"my_function1")?;
            return Ok(func());
        }
        Ok(true)
    }
}
```

I will only get a result: `GetProcAddress failed`.

I wonder is it able to call a c# class in dll using rust?

If we are able to do it, how?

Comment: Can you make your C# function static by chance? Your current code wouldn't even work in C# by the way, because you would need to create an instance of the class before calling its method.

Comment: To use a .net library you would need to [host the .net runtime in your process](https://crates.io/crates/netcorehost). I would expect it to use C-style calls, so the usage of actual objects will likely be limited.

Comment: @frankenapps hard to do it. I'm aware of that, just take a final try to make some progress. ready to learn c# now, thanks for your help!

Comment: @JonasH I'll take a try and ready to start learning c#... thanks for your help!